# cell.accessoryType is not visible and tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: doesn't works

Tags: uitableview

I've a customized split view for iPad, on the left part I have the KalController (https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) the calendar component and the tableView with the events of the selected day on the Kal Date Picker.

On the other hand, I have another subview ont the right with an standard UITableView listing the next events.

When one of the rows is selected on the Kal tableView, the right TableView push the detail view of the event on the navigation Controller.

But, I don't know why, althought the rows of both UITableView has the same code, the second table view, (the right one) present two problems:
 - The cells has no cell.accessoryType
 - Althought the Controller has the delegate properly set, the method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: was never been raised ...

Anybody knows if there is any restriction of the number of TableViews to be displayed in the same View ... I believe should be posible ... but something doesn't works.

Of course, in The NIB the UITableView has properly set the dataSource and delegate...

Any suggestion?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Solved ...

the problem was the height of the rows.

In the test behaviour I had just one row, and this is the reason because it has been displayed perfectly.